# How to include common xml files in 2 projects without copying/duplicating them

Tags: java, xml, ant

I have a set of xml files which are imported in ant  build files of 2 different projects. Now those xml files are duplicated in 2 projects. How do I make them a single copy and use them in both the projects.

Comment: are the xml files used only during ant builds? or are they packaged with the projects? if you want to package them with the projects, put them into a common jar and the have the projects include that jar

Comment: yes they are used only during the builds.

Comment: How do I implement if they are only used when ant builds.?

Answer (score 0):

Use either import:

```
<import file="your_path/your_file.xml" as="" prefixSeparator=""/>
```

Or include:

```
<include file="your_path/your_file.xml"/>
```